# Помогите с регулярным выражением на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, callback, pcre

Использую PHP 8.2
Есть текст:

```
<p>The random module in Python provides various functions to generate random numbers.</p><h2 id="methods">Generating random numbers within a specific range</h2><p>In Python, generating random numbers within a specific range is a common requirement in various applications.</p>
```

Я написал код, для замены части слов на заглавные буквы.

```
$res = preg_replace_callback(
    "#(numbers|random|module)#m",
    function (array $matches) {
       return strtoupper($matches[0]);
    },
    $res
);
```

Но мне необходимо чтобы эти замены осуществлялись ТОЛЬКО ВНУТРИ тегов `<p>`. И при этом ничего не менялось внутри тегов `<h2>` и других тегах.
Как это сделать?

Comment: так надо сначала извлечь эти `<p>` и с ними уже работать.  А если будет `<p><a>module</a></p>` то это что будет?